# How to send files to a Node.js server using Axios as an http client?

Tags: node.js, http, axios

I'm using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) on the client side to send HTTP requests to a remote Node.js server. How might I go about sending files in the request body using Axios? I also have to send other information in the request body - sending just the files to the server will not suffice. How might I go about doing this? I am open to using a different HTTP client as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) instance. On node you can use the [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) npm package. Then you just send that `FormData` instance as the `data` in an axios request.

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("username", "Groucho");
formData.append("accountnum", 123456); // number 123456 is immediately converted to a string "123456"

// HTML file input, chosen by user
formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);

// JavaScript file-like object
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

axios.post("http://foo.com/submitform.php", formData);
```